# Pressing Button/Div on Webpage with Python Script

Tags: python, html, selenium, automation

This may be a long shot, but I am really hoping there is some way! To give background, I have been working on an Algorithmic Trader in Python and want to periodically automatically buy assets with it, specifically crypto.

I have a URL: https://testnet.phemex.com/spot/trade/BTCUSDT
to the exchange I am trying to use. The above is their Testnet, but here is their live trading page for trading BTCUSDT: https://phemex.com/spot/trade/BTCUSDT

They have reasonable fees, but at the rate I am trading, I am trying to avoid fees. The kicker is that their trading is free on web or mobile but there is a 0.1% fee on API trades. Because of this, I can't profitably use their API. So, I was curious if there was a function that could be created as a work-around, automating a simple number of clicks on the web-page.

So, I have a function that signals when to buy or sell. Once this is determined, I want one function that when called, buys the asset on the webpage and another that sells.

This works pretty simply and can be accomplished by three button clicks in both cases.

Looking at a screenshot:

[image]

I simply need to click the buy button, the 100% button and the green "Buy BTC" button to quite obviously, buy!

To Sell I need to do the same exact thing except click sell first as seen in a screenshot below:

[image]

I am not sure if this is even possible, as I do not have much experience interacting with webpages via Python but would greatly appreciate any help or advice anyone could offer. A function to perform these tasks on the webpage would be amazingly helpful! Thanks for any assistance offered, and please let me know if I can guide in any way or clarify anything!

-Revised-
This is what I believe to be the html
`<div class="wrap pr df fdc p16 pb8 svelte-9kakd1"><div class="wrap df T2 f14 ovh svelte-4kgq9l"><span class="f1 tc cp svelte-4kgq9l buy">BUY</span> <span class="f1 tc cp svelte-4kgq9l sell-border">SELL</span></div> <div class="f14 lh32 fw2 wsn usn T2 bb  svelte-193fcus" style="display:flex; margin-top: 10px;"><div class="wrap pr lh40 cp T3 svelte-2y43eg active">Limit</div> <div class="wrap pr lh40 cp T3 svelte-2y43eg">Market</div> <div class="wrap pr lh40 cp T3 svelte-2y43eg">Conditional</div></div> <div class="f1 pr"><div><div><div class="mt16"><span class="svelte-vtfoqq df"><input class="fw2 T2 svelte-vtfoqq" type="text"> <label class="wsn T3 svelte-vtfoqq">Limit Price USDT</label> <button disabled="" class="svelte-vtfoqq"></button> <button class="svelte-vtfoqq"></button></span></div> <div class="mt16 df mb10"><div class="f1 mr16" style="margin-top: 3px;"><span class="svelte-vtfoqq df"><input class="fw2 T2 svelte-vtfoqq" type="text"> <label class="wsn T3 svelte-vtfoqq">Amount to Receive</label> <button disabled="" class="svelte-vtfoqq"></button> <button class="svelte-vtfoqq"></button></span></div> <div style="width: 60px;"><div class="wrap pr lh40 T2 svelte-1bqfv8r"><div class="df"><span class="f1 cp wp100 cb ml4 svelte-1bqfv8r">BTC</span> <i class="iconfont arrow pa svelte-1bqfv8r"></i></div> <ul class="pa B3 svelte-1bqfv8r"><li class="T2 cp svelte-1bqfv8r"><span class="f1 cp wp100 cb ml4">BTC</span> </li><li class="T2 cp svelte-1bqfv8r"><span class="f1 cp wp100 cb ml4">USDT</span> </li></ul></div></div></div> <div class="wrap df f12 lh20 svelte-1cl6icl"><div class="f1 item tc cp svelte-1cl6icl">25%</div><div class="f1 item tc cp svelte-1cl6icl">50%</div><div class="f1 item tc cp svelte-1cl6icl">75%</div><div class="f1 item tc cp svelte-1cl6icl">100%</div></div> <div class="mt12"><div class="df f1 lh20 f12 wsn jcsb" style=""><span class="T3">Max Buy</span><span class="ml4 T2">0.000000 BTC</span></div> <div class="df f1 lh20 f12 wsn jcsb" style="margin-top: 5px;"><span class="T3">Available Balance</span><span class="ml4 T2">0.00 USDT</span></div></div> <div class="df mt8"><button class="ga svelte-1cyhsgj buy" data-gac="order.spot" data-gaa="link_click" data-gal="spot.place_order" disabled=""><div class="pv8"><div class="lh18 f14">Buy BTC</div> <div class="f12 mt2"><span class="op6 svelte-wd4vpe">Cost</span> 0.00 USDT</div></div></button></div> <div class="usn mt8"><div class="wrap pr lh40 T2 svelte-1bqfv8r"><div class="df"><span class="f1 cp wp100 cb ml4 svelte-1bqfv8r">GoodTillCancel</span> <i class="iconfont arrow pa svelte-1bqfv8r"></i></div> <ul class="pa B3 svelte-1bqfv8r"><li class="T2 cp svelte-1bqfv8r"><span class="f1 cp wp100 cb ml4">GoodTillCancel</span> </li><li class="T2 cp svelte-1bqfv8r"><span class="f1 cp wp100 cb ml4">ImmediateOrCancel</span> </li><li class="T2 cp svelte-1bqfv8r"><span class="f1 cp wp100 cb ml4">FillOrKill</span> </li></ul></div></div></div></div>  </div></div>`

Buy Button: `<span class="f1 tc cp svelte-4kgq9l buy">BUY</span>`

Sell Button: `<span class="f1 tc cp svelte-4kgq9l sell-border">SELL</span>`

100% Button: `<div class="f1 item tc cp svelte-1cl6icl">100%</div>`

Execute Button: `<div class="df mt8"><button class="ga svelte-1cyhsgj buy" data-gac="order.spot" data-gaa="link_click" data-gal="spot.place_order" disabled=""><div class="pv8"><div class="lh18 f14">Buy BTC</div> <div class="f12 mt2"><span class="op6 svelte-wd4vpe">Cost</span> 0.00 USDT</div></div></button></div>`

Comment: Can you include the full html code for the elements in question.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan, is what I added what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('yoururl')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[.='BUY']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[.='100%']"))).click()
```

Should be simple to click the BUY or the 100% element.